# how + adjective + noun + verb

Tags: grammar

Why do we say "Look at how easy it is" instead of "Look at how easy is it?"
I understand the second one sounds like a question, but if "it" is the subject of the clause what is "how easy?"

Comment: What is your question? "*Why do we say...*"? "*What is 'how easy'"? Something else?

Comment: This is an embedded exclamative clause, not an embedded interrogative. However, these two types of clause often look identical.

Answer (score 1):

Interrogative content clauses like "how easy it is" *do* show Wh-movement (that is: the question word always goes at the beginning), but *don't* show inversion (that is: the subject appears before the verb, not the other way 'round). The non-interrogative version would be something like, "Look, it's *so easy*!"

> […] if "it" is the subject of the clause what is "how easy?"

It's just an adjective phrase, the complement of *is*.

By comparison, here is an analogous series of examples with *what*:

- "Look, it's a car!"
- "Look what it is!" (interrogative content clause: Wh-movement, but no inversion)
- "What is it?" (question: both Wh-movement and inversion)

and here's one with *where*:

- "Look, it's over there!"
- "Look where it is!" (interrogative content clause: Wh-movement, but no inversion)
- "Where is it?" (question: both Wh-movement and inversion)

Comment: _Look at how easy it is_ is perfectly grammatical and about as common as _Look_ alone. _Lookit_ has become a unit in many people's English and doesn't need an object.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Hmm, you're right. For some reason it sounded really weird to me, but Googling, I find examples that sound natural. I'll remove that claim.